# random.choice always returns false

Tags: python

Whenever I run this code, it always picks the False value. I tried changing the positions of **True and False**, but it does not seem to make a difference.

```
import random


set = {'key1':50, 'key2':100, 'key3':500}

answer = int(input('What number would you like to place: '))

answer1 = int(input('What will be your wager: '))

random.choice([True,False])

if random.choice == True:
    print('YOU WON!')
else: 
    print('YOU LOST!')
    
if random.choice == True:
    print('Your current balance is: {answer1*2}')
else:
    print('Your current balance is: 0$')
```

Comment: You are checking the truthyness of the `random.choice` function itself, which will always be `True`, not the return value

Comment: `random.choice` is a function, not a boolean value. It's not True or False.

Comment: You are not saving the result of `choice()` and then you are comparing *the function* to `True`.

Comment: @mousetail His check will actually be false all the time. `==` does not check "truthyness", it checks for an exact `True`.

Comment: @KlausD. You are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't choose between True and False in your code. You need to do it like this:

```
if random.choice([True, False]):
    .....
```

Comment: Or just `if random.choice([True,False]):`

Comment: Except that the two `if`'s will frequently get different truth values.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the following:

```py
result = random.choice([True,False])

if result:
   ...
else:
   ...
```

As others in their comments already pointed out, `random.choice` is a function instance (an object in Python) which is not called here and returns something like this:

```py
<bound method Random.choice of <random.Random object at 0x558365b16cd0>>
```

which is neither `True` nor `False`, hence comparing it with `True` always returns `False`.

Comment: "when called without parameters" this might seem nitpicky, but I feel this should be reworded. A [*call*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) in Python has a specific meaning, it is a kind of expression, and in this case, you are referring to an object without calling it. And bound methods are a common type of object that are involved in call expressions frequently.

Comment: I agree. My original aim was to keep the explanation simple and understandable, despite being to some extend inaccurate. That's why I put it in italic. I can rephrase it.

Answer (score 1):

if because you compare the literal value `True` with a function (`random.choice`).

You need save the value of `random.choice([True,False])`
in a variable and them you can use the variable in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice` is a function - it will never equal `True` or `False`. `random.choice == True` and `random.choice == False` are both `False`. It looks like you want to make the random choice once and use it in the rest of your code. So save that value to a variable.

```
import random

set = {'key1':50, 'key2':100, 'key3':500}

answer = int(input('What number would you like to place: '))

answer1 = int(input('What will be your wager: '))

result = random.choice([True, False])
if result:
    print('YOU WON!')
else: 
    print('YOU LOST!')
    
if result:
    print('Your current balance is: {answer1*2}')
else:
    print('Your current balance is: 0$')
```